# c++: is there a memory leak when resident memory is increasing slowly?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have a c++ program, its resident memory increase slowly, whilst its virtual memory remains unchanged basically. So is this a memory leak?

After reading some articles, and running some tests, I find that if the free memory is 2G (use `free` command), and run this code:

```
int main() {
    while (1) {
        int* a = new int[100000];
    }
}
```

use `top` command to see that the resident memory is less than 2G, and remains unchanged, but virtual memory is increasing so fast.

so whether I can say that

- when there is a memory leak, the virtual memory must increase.
- but if resident memory is going up and down, virtual memory remain unchanged, it is not the memory leak

Edit: I do this on linux

I rewrite my code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    while (1) {
        int* a = new int[100000];
        std::memset(a, 0, sizeof(a));
        a[0] += 1;
    }
}
```

and free command:

               `total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:             3          0          3          0          0          0
-/+ buffers/cache:          0          3
Swap:            3          0          3`

when run code above:

`PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND

  8518 wq       20   0  358g 2.9g  704 R 53.9 73.8   0:09.13 a.out`

the `RES` increase to ~3g, then stop,also code below:

```
    #include <iostream>
int main() {
    while (1) {
        int* a = new int[100000];
    }
}
```

so the final question, in which way the resident memory increase, but not the virtual, can I say that maybe free memory increase, os can allocate more physical memory to the progress

Comment: The OS/runtime you are running on is smart enough to notice that you never actually use the memory you allocate. It will just mark the memory as "reserved" for you but not actually give it to you until you use it. Try writing some data into the allocated memory and see it change.

Comment: having a `new` without a matching `delete` is a memory leak, full stop.

Comment: This is an infinite loop with no observable side effect. This is undefined behavior.

Comment: Use some code analysis tool like valgrind's memcheck.

Comment: @NathanOliver what do you mean 'full stop'

Comment: @wang No need to go any further.  As soon as you don't have a match you have a leak.

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention your platform. On systems like Linux, there is a lazy memory allocator. This means that if you call `new` to allocate memory that is not initialized (as with your int array), then virtual memory will be allocated but not physical memory. Later, if you do assign a value to the memory, it does get allocated.

As nwp says, try assigning values to your allocated memory (either by using something like `memset` or using a class with a constructor that initializes the class members).