# Why does new int[n] seem to not allocate memory for n ints?

Tags: c++

I wrote this code, allowing me to see memory allocation happening via the task manager/memory usage (I'm running this on Windows 10).

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>

void allocateIntBlock(const int numInts)
{
    new int[numInts];
    // Return without deallocating.
}

void allocateIntRepeat(const int numInts)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < numInts; ++i) {
        new int;
    }
    // Return without deallocating.
}



const int numThings = 120000000;


int main()
{
    allocateIntRepeat(numThings);
    system("pause");
}
```

If I call `allocateIntRepeat()`, which repeatedly allocates *n* `int`s, I can see the memory usage increasing. If I instead call `allocateIntBlock()`, which allocates a single block of *n* `int`s, it doesn't seem as if any allocation happened at all.

I would expect `new int[n]` to allocate exactly the same amount of memory as calling `new int` *n* times.

This is the assembly from [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/dssldW). Can someone explain what is happening under the hood with new[] and/or guide me through the assembly to help me understand why these two ways of allocation are different?

```
allocateIntBlock(int):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        movsx   rdx, eax
        movabs  rax, 2305843009213693950
        cmp     rdx, rax
        ja      .L2
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        cdqe
        sal     rax, 2
        jmp     .L4
.L2:
        call    __cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length
.L4:
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    operator new[](unsigned long)
        nop
        leave
        ret
allocateIntRepeat(int):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 32
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], edi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
.L7:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        cmp     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
        jge     .L8
        mov     edi, 4
        call    operator new(unsigned long)
        add     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
        jmp     .L7
.L8:
        nop
        leave
        ret
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     edi, 120000000
        call    allocateIntRepeat(int)
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Comment: The assembly is not helpful. All it shows is calls to `operator new` and `operator new[]`. Can you clarify if you think this behavior is unexpected and don't understand why it would happen or if you think the behavior is expected but want details on exactly what's going on in detail? That would produce two different answers to this question. (Explaining why you should expect this behavior is just a few simple sentences. Would that answer your question?)

Comment: Are you on Linux?

Comment: Note: It is really hard to see actual memory usage with task manager. A modern OS is pretty smart about how it doles out memory. If you ask for storage and never use it, the OS may do nothing other than mark off the fact that the program asked for it. It probably will not deliver any memory until you actually use it.

Comment: related/maybe dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45962989/c-is-there-a-memory-leak-when-resident-memory-is-increasing-slowly

Comment: You're not storing the pointer returned from `new` so maybe the compiler is able to deduce that the memory can never be used after allocating it. Is it being optimized away?

Comment: @user4581301 It's not hard to see the **virtual memory footprint** of a process, though.

Comment: @Kaz good point. I should have used proper terminology.

Comment: The large single block is never accessed, so it never gets paged in. But when you allocate lots of tiny blocks, there is heap bookkeeping between each block, so each page gets accessed and counts to working set.

Comment: If you don’t replace operator new, I think the compiler is allowed to optimize the whole thing out completely, leaving a single system pause call.